# Java compiler/interpreter

Tags: java, compiler-construction, terminology

Why we do we say that Java is a compiled and interpreted language?

What is the advantage of this (being compiled and interpreted)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Java is compiled to an intermediate "byte code" at compilation time.  This is in contrast to a language like C that is compiled to machine language at compilation time.  The Java byte code cannot be directly executed on hardware the way that compiled C code can.  Instead the byte code must be interpreted by the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) at runtime in order to be executed.  The primary drawback of a language like C is that when it is compiled, that binary file will only work on one particular architecture (e.g. x86).

Interpreted languages like PHP are effectively system independent and rely on a system and architecture specific interpreter.  This leads to much greater portability (the same PHP scripts work on Windows machines and Linux machines, etc.). However, this interpretation leads to a significant performance decrease.  High-level languages like PHP require more time to interpret than machine-specific instructions that can be executed by the hardware.

Java seeks to find a compromise between a purely compiled language (with no portability) and a purely interpreted language (that is significantly slower).  It accomplishes this by compiling the code into a form that is closer to machine language (actually, Java byte code is a machine language, simply for the Java Virtual Machine), but can still be easily transported between architectures.  Because Java still requires a software layer for execution (the JVM) it is an interpreted language.  However, the interpreter (the JVM) operates on an intermediate form known as byte code rather than on the raw source files.  This byte code is generated at compile time by the Java compiler.  Therefore, Java is also a compiled language.  By operating this way, Java gets some of the benefits of compiled languages, while also getting some of the benefits of interpreted languages.  However, it also inherits some limitations from both of these languages.

As Bozho points out, there are some strategies for increasing the performance of Java code (and other byte code languages like .Net) through the use of Just in Time (JIT) compilation.  The actual process varies from implementation to implementation based on the requirements, but the end-result is that the original code is compiled into byte code at compile time, but then it is run through a compiler at runtime before it is executed.  By doing this, the code can be executed at near-native speeds.  Some platforms (I believe .Net does this) save the result of the JIT compilation, replacing the byte code.  By doing this, all future executions of the program will execute as though the program was natively compiled from the beginning.

Comment: "Interpreted languages like PHP are completely system independent" -- not entirely true: [`pow(2,36)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) will give `6.87194767360e+10` on a 32-bit system and `68719476736` on a 64-bit system.

Comment: A minor nitpick - but byte code is machine language.  There is nothing stopping you from having a physical machine that implements the JVM specifications.  In that case, the byte code would be directly executed on hardware and there would be no need for a software layer or interpretation.

Comment: @amphetamachine Fair enough, how about "effectively"?

Comment: @emory - true, very true.  I simplified it for the sake of explanation, I'll edit to be more correct

Comment: awesome simple explanation.

Answer (score 14):

> Why do we say Java is compiled and interpreted language.

Because source code (`.java` files) is *compiled* into bytecode (`.class` files) that is then *interpreted* by a [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) (also known as a JVM) for execution (the JVM can do further optimization but this is anoher story).

> What is the advantage over this(being compiled/interpreted)

Portability. The **same** bytecode can be executed on any platform as long as a JVM is installed ("compile once, run anywhere").

Answer (score 6):

This is a long topic and you'd better read about [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). In short, Java is compiled to bytecode, and the bytecode is later compiled (in the JVM) to machine code.

Answer (score 3):

Java is considered a "compiled" language because code is *compiled* into bytecode format that is then run by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). This gives several advantages in the realm of performance and code optimization, not to mention ensuring code correctness.

It is considered an "interpreted" language because, after the bytecode is compiled, it is runnable on any machine that has a JVM installed. It is in this way that Java is much like an interpreted language in that, for the most part, it doesn't depend on the platform on which is is being run. This behavior is similar to other interpreted languages such as Perl, Python, PHP, etc.

One theoretical downside to the fact that Java programs can be run on any system in absence of the source code is that, while this method of distribution ensures cross-platform compatibility, the developers have one less reason to release their source code, driving a wedge between the ideological meanings of the phrases "cross-platform" and "open source".

Answer (score 2):

Java is compiled, into byte code not binaries. The byte codes are not executable directly, they need the Java Virtual Machine to do a just in time compile and compile them again into machine code at runtime.

At a very basic level, it separate the code that programmers write from the local machine where the JVM operates on, hence better portability. While compiling to bytecode helps the performance of just in time compile, reduce file sizes, and more or less help conceal real code. (it also eliminates some compile time error)

Answer (score 1):

Compiled: Your program is syntactically a correct Java program, before the program starts.

Interpreted: Run on different platforms the same (byte-)code.

Compiled: When your program has compiled correctly you can be shure to have 80% of software bugs under control. And your code will not stop because you have not correctly closed a code block, etc.

Interpreted: You know what Applets are ? It was the "killer" application when Java came out. Your browser downloads the applet from the website and run the applet code in your browser. That is not very cool. But, the same applet runs on Windows, Linux, Macs, Solaris, ... because runs/interpreted an intermedium language: the byte code.

Comment: the answer is very abstract .Can u please elobrate